# \mathbb not working in \underset

Tags: amsmath, mathtools, amssymb

I'm trying to put `\mathbb{R}` in an `\underset` of `\sup` in the following way:

```
\underset{x \in \mathbb{R}}{\sup}
```

However this sequence does not render as usual. I use following libraries:

```
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
```

I'm new to LaTeX and not sure how to approach this problem. Please help.

Full MWE to reproduce this:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}
\let\memoldbibsection\bibsection
\let\bibsection\relax
\usepackage[nobysame]{amsrefs}
\let\bibsection\memoldbibsection 
\usepackage[right=2.7cm,left=3.5cm, top=2.7cm, bottom=2.5cm,includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeindex
\makeindex[sym]


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}


\makeatletter

\begin{document}
$\underset{x \in \mathbb{R}}{\sup}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, can you add your complete MWE starting to \documentclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you delete `\usepackage{flexisym}` it works well.

In my experience, to put so many packages, often it create conflict or bad compilation. It is important, also, the order of the list the various packages.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}    

$\underset{x \in \mathbb{R}}{\sup}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14):

The problem is caused by package `flexisym`. Not only `\mathbb{R}` is affected but also `\sup` is in an italic font.
Anyway, `\underset` is not the right command for putting something below the "operator" `\sup`. This is done by a subscript. Compare:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{flexisym}

\begin{document}
\[
  \underset{x \in \mathbb{R}}{\sup} = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

If you do not need package `flexisym`, then do not load it.

Comment: Of course, I voted in favour of your next answer because it was more comprehensive than mine.